Why do operational logs end up in the debug log?
I've created an application in .Net Framework 4.6.2 which logs to the event log by extending the EventSource class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource?view=net-6.0).
I've recently had to migrate the app from x86 to x64 to get round a bug in Windows and I'm now noticing the following behaviour:

Writing the Admin event log works fine
Writing to the Operational event log has the following weird behaviour

x86 in launched from Visual Studio works fine
x86 running manually works fine
x64 in launched from Visual Studio works fine
x64 running manually write Operational event logs to the debug log (When enabled) Debug logs don't appear to log anywhere



Edit:
I managed to get it working by changing the following line
public static EventManager Log = new EventManager();

To
    public static EventManager Log = new EventManager(false);

    public EventManager(bool throwOnEventWriteErrors) : base(throwOnEventWriteErrors)
    {
    }

Where EventManager is the class used to store all my Events such as:
        [Event(2, Message = "Operational Event", Level = EventLevel.Informational, Channel = EventChannel.Operational)]
    public void OperationalEvent() { WriteEvent(2); }

I have no idea why this worked but I'm guessing that the explicit call to the EventSource base class triggers some kind of different code path that works round whatever the underlying issue was...

This won't fix your implementation. But I've seen all kinds of errors while writing to the event log. A good solution is to use a logging framework like Serilog or NLog since their implementation has already been tested and bugfixed over many years.

Are you missing permissions? You can let your application run under procdump which will print all exceptions to console and create a memory dump for every Exception: procdump -ma -e 1 -n 10 -x c:\temp\ YourApp.exe See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump. This will create up to 10 dumps for first chance exceptions which will be written to c:\temp folder and it will launch YourApp.exe.

How do you log to the event log exactly? Is there some example codes?

Added code example and a workaround that I found after MANY hours of bashing my head against the wall. Thanks for the suggestions and if any one knows why this workaround works I'd be very interested to hear :)
